# Odoo 11 Nginx Reverse Proxy Index of /

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, odoo-11

I have a odoo 11 installation behind a Nginx proxy. Its been working for a while but now when you access it, its showing index of / instead of Odoo login page (see screenshot).

[image]

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
#odoo server

upstream odoo {

 server 127.0.0.1:8069;

}

upstream odoochat {

 server 127.0.0.1:8072;

}



# http -> https

server {

   listen 80;

   server_name businessapps.enone.tech;

   #server_name odoo;

   rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;

}



server {

 listen 443;

 server_name businessapps.enone.tech;

 #server_name odoo;

 proxy_read_timeout 720s;

 proxy_connect_timeout 720s;

 proxy_send_timeout 720s;



 # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode

 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;



 # SSL parameters

 ssl on;

 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/businessapps.enone.tech/fullchain.pem;

 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/businessapps.enone.tech/privkey.pem;

 ssl_session_timeout 30m;

 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

 ssl_ciphers '<replaced cipher>';

 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



 # log

 access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;

 error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;



 # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port

 location /longpolling {

   proxy_pass http://odoochat;

 }



 # Redirect requests to odoo backend server

 location / {

   proxy_redirect off;

   proxy_pass http://odoo;

 }



 # common gzip

 gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;

 gzip on;

}
```

Can someone point out what could be the issue. Sometimes I can access the login page, other times I get the index of / page. The installation is on Ubuntu 16.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the directory in the nginx config, and I had this error previously and found that even once changing my config I had weird errors with odoo, so I recommend you do what I did and that is completely re install Nginx and ensure you reboot your server after having done so!

Comment: After re installing Nginx everything started working well?

Comment: Perfectly and ive never had an issue since

Answer (score 0):

Add location block inside server {} (block)

I have used below nginx configuration

```
upstream odooapp {
    server odoo:8069;
    keepalive 8;
}

upstream longpolling {
    server odoo:8072;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name businessapps.enone.tech;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log mainlog;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    return 301 https://businessapps.enone.tech:443/web/login;

 }

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name businessapps.enone.tech;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log mainlog;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ssl_ciphers                 ALL:!ADH:!MD5:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ssl_certificate <PATH_TO_CERT>;
    ssl_certificate_key <PATH_TO_KEY>;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=2592000; preload;" always;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      proxy_connect_timeout 300;
      proxy_send_timeout 300;
      proxy_read_timeout 300;
      send_timeout 300;
      client_max_body_size 20M;

      proxy_pass http://odooapp/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /longpolling {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

      proxy_pass http://longpolling/longpolling;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
```